# iText - Generating text file from pdf with Chinese characters

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText for extraction of data from PDFs. My application is able to read PDFs with English characters, but we found a new file with Chinese characters. When I tried to extract that data, I get an error:

```
ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized.
```

So I added `itext-asian.jar`. Now I am not getting an error, but `getTextFromPage()`
returns an empty string.  Am I missing something?

```
PdfReader pr = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
// get the number of pages in the document
PdfTextExtractor pte =
    new PdfTextExtractor(pr, new CustomLocationAwarePdfRenderListener(scanDepth));
int pNum = pr.getNumberOfPages();

String text = "";
// extract text from each page and write it to the output text file
for (int page = 1; page <= pNum; page++) {
    text = text.concat("\n").concat(pte.getTextFromPage(page));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577944/itext-generating-pdf-with-chinese-characters-chinese-simplified

Comment: @FastSnail the OP claims he already did what is the recommendation from the accepted answer, i.e. adding itext-asian.jar...

Comment: anybody have solution plz suggest...