# ITEXT 2.7 PDF cant Display Chinese Characters

Tags: java, itext

```
BaseFont CNFont= BaseFont.createFont(pathTotff, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font font = new Font(CNFont, 24);

 private static void addChineseText(Document document, Font font) {
            try {
    //          Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
    //          char[] aa = String.toCharArray();
    //          StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
    //          boolean isLastChineseChar = false;
    //
    //          // Process HTML content character by character
    //          for (int j = 0; j < String.length(); j++) {
    //
    //              if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(aa[j]) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS) {
    //                  if (!isLastChineseChar) {
    //                      par.add(new Phrase(newLine.toString()));
    //                      newLine.delete(0, newLine.length());
    //                  }
    //                  newLine.append(aa[j]);
    //                  isLastChineseChar = true;
    //              } else {
    //                  if (isLastChineseChar) {
    //                      par.add(new Phrase(newLine.toString(), font));
    //                      newLine.delete(0, newLine.length());
    //                      isLastChineseChar = false;
    //                  }
    //                  newLine.append(aa[j]);
    //              }
    //          }
    //
    //          // Add the remaining text to the document based on the last character type
    //          if (isLastChineseChar) {
    //              par.add(new Phrase(newLine.toString(), font));
    //          } else {
    //              par.add(new Phrase(newLine.toString()));
    //          }
    //
    //          document.add(par);
                HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
                StyleSheet styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
                styleSheet.loadTagStyle(HtmlTags.SPAN, HtmlTags.FONT, font.getFamilyname());
    
                worker.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
                worker.parse(new StringReader(String));
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to display the chinese characters with itext 2.7 pdf, but I noticed that even though the Chinese Characters are in the 'String' variable, they will not be displayed after executing the line of parsing.

I have tried to use the solution provided in [IText - Generating PDF with Chinese characters (Chinese Simplified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577944/itext-generating-pdf-with-chinese-characters-chinese-simplified?rq=3) (which is the commented out code), but it will only display the plain string from the 'String' variable, and not converting them to html. Besides that, I have also tried to use the setStyleSheet and fontSelector method, but the chinese characters will be omitted in the end results.

I have tried to use SIMSUN.tff and arialuni.tff